# What is the number of shortest paths from $A$ to $B$? (IJMO problem)

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, contest-math

What is the number of shortest paths from $A$ to $B$? We measure by the number of steps (not by length)

[image]

---

**Attempt:**

Notice that we should just consider 2 types of step: *right* and *down*. The longest path clearly required 8 steps. The longest 8-step path uses only short lines. Notice that if we use a long line one time, then it saves one short line (it is either *right, right* or *down, down*). Notice also if we use the hypotenuse line, then it is the same as two steps: *right,down* or *down,right*.

Now a shortest path consists only of 6 steps. These can be attained when we use 2 shortcuts: either using 2 long lines, or using 1 long line and 1 hypotenuse line.

There is only one shortest path that uses 2 long lines, the path is from $A$ to the top right, then straight to $B$.

There are only 2 shortest paths that use 1 long line and 1 hypotenuse.

So the total number of shortest paths is 3.

Are there better or simpler ways to solve the problem?

Comment: Imprtant clarification: Do you measure length in number of steps from one intersection to the next, or in physical / Euclidean length?

Comment: @Arthur by number of steps

Comment: I count 10 paths of length 6....

Comment: And the two corners count as vertices, even though they aren't really intersections?

Comment: Looks fine to me. Maybe you could write another sentence why one can't use 3 shortcuts for a paths of length 5.

Comment: This can be considered as belonging to graph theory.

Comment: I count $5$ paths of length $6$.  The path along the top and right edges, and the $4$ paths used by using the diagonal short cut ($2$ unique ways to get to the shortcut and $2$ ways to get from the end of the short cut to point $B$).

Answer (score 2):

Let us work backward in this problem : we define an "algorithm" (there's a small issue) that will attach to each vertex, two numbers : the length of the shortest path from that vertex to $B$, along with the number of such shortest paths. For any vertex, we attach a $2$ tuple indicating these parameters.

This is very simple : start with labelling $B$ as $(0,0)$. Next, label all neighbours of $B$ as $(1,1)$. Then , proceeding to their neighbours and so on, do the following at each vertex:

- Check the following condition visually(this is the issue : I'd need to know how to algorithmically do this properly, but for a small graph visuals work) : all vertices which are strictly closer to $B$ than it, are labelled. Else, go to another vertex.
- If so, find the minimum of all the first labels of its neighbors, and add $1$ to the minimum : that is the first part of the label of this graph. Next, find how many neighbours attain the minimum : add the second labels of all these vertices, and you have the second label of your vertex.

Here's how my algorithm worked :

[image: Algo]

Let me explain the algorithm for a few cases.

$B,E,G$ should be obvious. Let us look at $D$. Every vertex of distance smaller than $D$ to $B$ is already labelled. These are $E,G$ whose first labels are $1$. Hence, the minimum is $1$ so the first label of $D$ is $2$. Also, both $E$ and $G$ attain the minimum first label value of $1$, so adding their second labels gives $2$, so $D$ is assigned $(2,2)$.

Now, look at $F$. Note that $D$ is labelled by now. The minimum of the first label is $2$, so the first label of $F$ is $3$. Next, the only label attaining the minimum is of course $D$, so its second label is $2$, which becomes the second label of $F$. So $F$ is assigned $(3,2)$.

Take $M$. By now, both of $Q,L$ will have been labelled. The minimum of their first labels is $4$, so the first label of $M$ is $5$. Next, the minimum is attained by both $Q$ and $L$, so the sum of their second labels is $3$, which we assign as second label to $M$. Thus $M$ is assigned $(5,3)$.

In this manner, if things are done correctly, then $A = (6,5)$, giving five paths. Furthermore, any path is given by a descent from $A \to B$ where the first labels decrease by $1$. In our case :

- AWQFDEB
- AWQFDGB
- AMQFDEB
- AMQFDGB
- AMLKJGB

Voila!

As to why the algorithm works, I leave you to see.

---

EDIT : one can algorithmically configure the "visually" part as follows : doing this with neighbours of $B$, proceed to doing it with "neighbours of neighbours", so in that case when you encounter a vertex, you can be confident that all "closer" vertices have been already labelled. Essentially, this is an induction by distance from $B$, like going from one layer of the onion to the next.

Answer (score 0):

Since you knew you must take either the diagonal edge or the right most edge, you can reduce the work significantly by considering paths going only through them.

`number of paths from A, distance from A`

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]